# Show that $\int_0^{2 \pi} \dfrac{d \theta}{5+4 \sin\theta}=\dfrac{2 \pi}{3}.$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, proof-verification, definite-integrals

By change of variable and letting $C_0$ be the unit circle about the origin, we have: 
\begin{align*}
\int_0^{2 \pi} \dfrac{d \theta}{5+4 \sin\theta} &= \int_{C_0} \dfrac{dz/zi}{5+4(z-z^{-1})/2i}\\
& = \int_{C_0} \dfrac{dz}{2z^2+5iz-2}\\
& = \int_{C_0} \dfrac{dz}{(z+i/2)(z+2i)}\\
& = 2 \pi i (-i/2+2i)^{-1}\\
& = \dfrac{4 \pi}{3}
\end{align*}

But [wolframalpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Cint_0%5E%7B2%20%5Cpi%7D%201%2F(5%2B4%20sinx)dx) gives $\dfrac{2 \pi}{3}.$ Is what I wrote valid?

Comment: What you've written is true, however, you may want to reference formulas that you're using (like Cauchy's integral formula), or why you can write $\sin(\theta)$ as you did (there you need to remark that $z=e^{i\theta}$ for $|z|=1.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\oint_{|z|=1} \frac {1}{i(2z^2 + 5iz -2} \ dz\\
\oint_{|z|=1} \frac {1}{2(z +2i)(z + \frac 12i)} \ dz$

You dropped a factor of $\frac 12$

$2\pi i\frac {1}{2(-\frac 12 i + 2i)} = \frac {2\pi}{3}$